# c# SaveFileDialog CSV add Varibles from Another part of the code

Tags: c#, csv

I have this code that works creating a CSV file (which I found on [This StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494651/saving-data-from-a-query-as-a-csv-file)).

```
private void saveCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    string filter = "CSV file (*.csv)|*.csv| All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = filter;
    const string header = "Header1, Header2, Header 3";
    StreamWriter writer = null;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filter = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        writer = new StreamWriter(filter);

        writer.WriteLine(header);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is write a second line to the CSV file, containing data from the section named

```
private void parseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

which has many strings, including Title, Firstname, and Lastname.

I've tried

```
string LineOneData = Title, Firstname, Lastname;
```

and then adding

```
writer.Write(LineOneData);
```

after the

```
writer.Write(header);
```

line, but I get the message (on the new string line) "The name Title does not exist in the current context"... which I am assuming is because the Dialog doesn't know anything about `parseFile_Click` section.

Can I get some advice please ?

Comment: what do you mean by "containing data from `private void parseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`". That's a void function, so there's no return value. Where is the content that you want to write actually being stored to (is there a string variable with it)? Could you please show the contents of `parseFile_Click`?

Comment: That `string LineOneData =  Title, Firstname , Lastname;` is illegal syntax, hence the compiler error. What are you trying to do? Are those three identifiers variables that you want to concatenate as one string? If so, you have to use the `+` sign, not the comma.

Answer (score 0):

If Title, Firstname and Lastname are variables you have to change

```
string LineOneData =  Title, Firstname , Lastname;
```

to

```
string LineOneData =  Title + "," + Firstname + "," + Lastname;
```

or

```
string LineOneData = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", Title, Firstname, Lastname);
```

Answer (score 0):

A crash course in terminologies first. It is called functions or methods, not sections. Now on to explaining the issue you are experiencing and proposing a solution to it.

```
private void saveCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    string filter = "CSV file (*.csv)|*.csv| All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = filter;
    const string header = "Header1, Header2, Header 3";
    StreamWriter writer = null;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filter = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        using( writer = new StreamWriter(filter) )
        {
            writer.WriteLine(header);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your other function, `parseFile_Click`, add the following lines to it

```
string LineOneData =  Title + "," + Firstname + "," + Lastname;
File.AppendAllText(filter, LineOneData);
```

This will append the information to generated CSV above. You do need to make sure that csv has been saved first. Otherwise you can guard against it by checking if filter points to a valid file, e.g., `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter) && File.Exists(filter)`.

Comment: Tanveer Badar , sorry about using the wrong terminology (I'm still learning). I've tried the code you have suggested , but I get told that "filter" does not exist in the current context. could you advise ?

Comment: OK, I think , with everyone here's help, and bit more google, I have found a solution.  If I add `string parsedTitle { get; set; }`
`string parsedFirstName { get; set; }`  in the Form1 method, then load them in the parseFile_Click method `parsedTitle = Title;` `parsedFirstName = FirstName;`, then I can reference them in the saveFileDialog1 method `string LineOneData = parsedTitle + "," + parsedFirstName; ' 'writer.WriteLine(LineOneData);`

Comment: I hope you are doing this for some homework assignment only.